# How to find probability current

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

I just can't find mistake in my calculations. Let's assume:
$$\hat{H}=\dfrac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+V(r),\quad \hat{p}^2=(-i\hbar\nabla)^2=-\hbar^2\Delta$$
Let's find:
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho(\vec{r},t)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\{\Psi^*(\vec{r},t)\Psi(\vec{r},t)\}=\Psi(\vec{r},t)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi^*(\vec{r},t)+\Psi(\vec{r},t)^*\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(\vec{r},t)=-\dfrac{i}{\hbar}\{\Psi\hat{H}\Psi^*+\Psi^*\hat{H}\Psi\}$$
But I have to get this:
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho(\vec{r},t)=\dfrac{i}{\hbar}\{(\hat{H}\Psi^*)\Psi-\Psi^*(\hat{H}\Psi)\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that by the time-dependent Schrödinger equation,

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\Psi(\vec{r},t) = \frac{-i}{\hbar} H \Psi(\vec{r},t)$$

So, taking the complex conjugate of both sides:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\Psi^*(\vec{r},t) = \frac{i}{\hbar} H \Psi^*(\vec{r},t)$$

That means that the first term should be

$$\Psi(\vec{r},t)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi^*(\vec{r},t) = \frac{i}{\hbar}\Psi(\vec{r},t) H \Psi^*(\vec{r},t)$$

whereas in your calculation you have it with a minus sign. After that you get the correct result.